# NativeScript: Why do the example apps have such a bad performance?

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am currently looking for a good framework for cross platform app development.

**NativeScript** seemed very promising, but the example apps are **so slow** on my iPhone 5S.

I tested the following from the Showcase:
- **Herd of Sheffield** (500-1000ms delay when switching tabs)
- **FK Zeljeznicar** (500-1000ms delay when visiting a tab for the first time)
- **ShoutOutPlay** (over 1000ms delay when opening a playlist of 60+ songs)

What are your experiences? Is the NativeScript performance really that bad?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: No issues for me with my apps. Those apps are showcases so while they might look good I don't think they've been put through any rigorous performance testing by the NativeScript team. Have you tried the NativeScript 'kitchen sink' app that's on the app stores? It's a bit heavy in usage of animations but it's from the NativeScript team so you can prob get answers as to why. Most performance issues can be overcome with just a little know how, as with any platform :) and next release (maybe tmrw, 2.4) has threading support for intensive operations.

Comment: I also tried the kitchen sink app. The performance is indeed better than the performance of the apps mentioned above. Still I experience a short delay of about 300ms before transitioning to a new view - but that's acceptable. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Would you be willing to give me the name of one of your apps so I can test their performance? Of course that's up to you.

Comment: The transitions can have a defined duration and I want to say the default is 300ms that might be why you see that :/ and the apps I've published are behind a login for closed systems so you wont be able to get in sorry. But I have some demo apps for my plugins on github. Can't think of many that are built out as an app since they just showcase the plugin though. You should join the slack channel if you decide to get into NativeScript lots of good developers there, very friendly and helpful.

Comment: Ok, I want to give NativeScript a shot. Thanks a lot Brad!